# SQL Join of 2 tables to subtract quantities using Java

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with an SQL query I am trying to execute.  I have two MYSQL tables as follows:

Table 1: **Orderdetails** with column name **QtyOrdered**

and

Table 2: **Titles** with column name **No_of_copies_in_inventory**

I would like to perform a SQL query where I can effectively update the No_of_copies_in_inventory in Titles table and do this

**No_of_copies_in_inventory in Titles**  = **No_of_copies_in_inventory - QtyOrdered**

Any input/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Input: google "sql join tutorial". Problem solved.

Comment: Generally speaking, one would perform this sort of update as part of the database transaction that posts the order...

Comment: Hello, thank you fancyPants.  I appreciate the suggestion about the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, eggyal, I am essentially trying to execute this query in a Java program.  In my program, I have a user who checks out a title and provides the qty.  I now want to update the inventory table qty so it reflects the # of titles user has checked out.  E.g. if Original qty is 10 and user checks out 1, then updated qty should be 9.

Comment: What I meant was, if your (Java) program has just inserted the relevant record into `Orderdetails`, then it ought still to have `QtyOrdered` to hand: there's no need to look it up from the table.  The usual approach would be to follow the `INSERT` into the first table with an `UPDATE` on the second, all within a single database transaction.  Alternatively, one might considered updating the second table from within an insertion trigger on the first table (depending on your application requirements).

Comment: Exactly eggyal.  You're right on the money.  I had tried to run this SQL query:  UPDATE Titles
LEFT JOIN Sub ON Titles.No_of_copies_in_inventory = Odetails.QtyOrdered
SET Titles.No_of_copies_in_inventory = (No_of_copies_in_inventory - QtyOrdered);  but ended up getting a "Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()." in Java...so I thought maybe my SQLquery was wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a uniquely indexed field (such as ID), you could do it this way:

```
UPDATE Orderdetails od
INNER JOIN Titles t ON od.id = t.id
SET t.No_of_copies_in_inventory = (t.No_of_copies_in_inventory - o.QtyOrdered)
WHERE od.id = 'idhere'
```

However, chances are you will have a variable stored for QtyOrdered and could simply use that rather than joining the tables